# How do I use CMake presets environment variables in the CMake build step?

Tags: c++, cmake, cmake-presets

I work with embedded software in Linux. Our vendor's compiler and linker require certain environment variables to be defined when building the binary.

What we do now is that we run a script in a shell to define these environment variables for us, then we run CMake in the same shell to build.

I started using [cmake-presets(7)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html) in the hope that I could define the environment variables under the `"environment"` key instead of running a script, like so:

```json
// CMakePresets.json
{
  "version": 4,
  "configurePresets": [
    {
      "name": "default"
      "environment": {
        "FOO": "some-value",
        "BAR": "some-other-value"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This works well for the CMake configure step (which requires the variables to be defined):

```bash
$ cmake --preset default -S /path/to/project -B /path/to/project/build
Preset environment variables:

  FOO="some-value"
  BAR="some-other-value"

(...)

Build files have been written to: /path/to/project/build
```

However, the environment variables are no longer defined when *building* the project:

```bash
$ cmake --build /path/to/project/build --target all
[  0%] Building CXX...
(...)
[  1%] Linking C static library libBaz.a
[vendor-linker] Error: FOO and BAR are undefined
```

Why are the environment variables only defined in the configure step? How can I propagate them to the build step?

I apologize for being unable to create a minimum working example. I don't know how to make a linker/compiler that throws an error when an env variable is undefined.

Comment: What does your CMakeLists.txt look like?

Comment: @jayatubi I am not allowed to share it unfortunately. I can say that it does directly refer to "$ENV{FOO}" in several places.

Comment: "the environment variables are no longer defined when building the project:" - Yes, environment variables set by a process are not propagated to the process which runs after it. Use build preset for control environment variables during the build. You may even inherit a build preset from the config one.

Comment: @Tsyvarev That's it! I had completely missed build presets! Thank you, that solved everything.